# C# access to SQL Server database stored procedures and views

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, view

In my C# application I need access to a SQL Server database. But only to some views and some stored procedures. Is it advisable to use Entity Framework? Or are there some lightweight methods to get access?

Comment: EF is pretty good by now - have a look at it! If you feel it's too bulky, you can always have a look at [Dapper.NET](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) (which is incidentally used to power this site here - Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it advisable to use entityframework?

Yes it is.

> Or ore there some lightweight methods to get access?

That is what Entity Framework is i believe.

Entity Framework + LINQ to SQL = Magic.

Comment: I use Entity Framework first time in a other projekt but with generating my own database with model first.
So now I need only access to a already existing database.

Model or code first is not working. I need database first. But I have not access to the complete database only to some views and stored procedure. I don't now how to start.

Comment: This might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1056400/Setting-up-SQLite-and-Entity-Framework-Code-First

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET is much faster than EF and there is no difficulty

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=DBNAME; Integrated Security=true;"))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, NAME FROM VIEWNAME where id > 4550;", conn))
    {
        // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure // for SP
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dictionary.Add(dr.GetInt32(0), dr.GetString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Connection string better store in app.config